# converting array of array into array of keyvalue pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert array of array into array of key-value pairs using javascript or jquery.

i have array of array like :

```
var arrOfarr = [[1,'One'],[2,'Two'],[3,'Three']];
```

how do i convert arrOfarr into the array of key-value pairs that looks like

```
[{id:1,text:'One'},{id:2,text:'Two'},{id:3,text:'Three'}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0, iLength = arrOfarr.length; i < iLength; i++) {
    result.push({ id: arrOfarr[i][0], text: arrOfarr[i][1] });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
arrOfarr = jQuery.map(arrOfarr, function(val){
    return {id: val[0], text: val[1]}
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wZpyZ/)

Comment: not exactly what op was asking for, if you look at his example (resulting objects should always have the properties `id` and `text`. At least if I didn't misunderstand.

Comment: You dont need jQuery for that, just use `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @user1983983 to support IE

Comment: I am not sure about browser support for `Array#map`. As jQuery seems to be already included (according to question tag), I would prefer @ArunPJohny version.

Comment: @Chips_100 only from IE >=9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrOfarr = [[1,'One'],[2,'Two'],[3,'Three']];
var hash = new Array(arrOfarr.length);
for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
    hash[x] = {id: arrOfarr[x][0], text: arrOfarr[x][1]};   
}
```

This might help you with performance if you have a large array or a lot of arrays because it'll allocate the size of the array in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arrOfarr.length; i++){
    var ar = arrOfarr[i];
    result.push({ id: ar[0], text: ar[1] });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
var arr = [[1,'One'],[2,'Two'],[3,'Three']];

var o = []
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    o.push({id: arr[i][0], text: arr[i][1]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
a=[[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three']];
$.each(a,function(id,value){
a[id]={id:value[0],text:value[1]};
});
```

now a will have three objects as you want.